# How to refresh a jsp page from another jsp page?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have two jsp pages. **groups.jsp** and **addGroup.jsp**

The addGroup JSP page is opened by clicking a button in groups.jsp and after clicking the "OK" button in **addGroup.jsp**, I'd like to refresh the **groups.jsp**. How will that be possible?

**addGroup.jsp**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function refresh() {                         
        //Refresh page implementation here
        window.close();
    }
</script>

//some code here
<table>
  <tr>
  <td>
     <h:commandButton id="buttonOK" value="#{common.ok}" type="button" styleClass="button" onclick="submitForm(); refresh();"/>
  <td>
  </tr>
</table>
//some code here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener)

> **objRef = window.opener;**
>
> Returns a reference to the window that opened this current window.

Try this in your case:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function refresh() {                         
        //Refresh page implementation here
        window.opener.location.reload();
        window.close();
    }
</script>
...
...
```